# With Right click with context_click in ruby I am unable to select the option to "Save the image"

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, browser-automation

I have been stuck with this for quite a while.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

def download
  d = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  d.get 'https://zinrelo.com'
  sleep 7
  photo = d.find_element(:class, 'aio-icon-img ')
  d.action.context_click(photo)
      .send_keys(:arrow_down)
      .send_keys(:enter).perform
  sleep 5
end

download
```

This code will do the right click but it would not select the save image option.

Chrome - **Version 78.0.3904.97**
Chrome Driver - **77.0.3865.40**
Selenium-Webdriver - **3.142.3**

Comment: Hi try to do in WATIR, which is a wrapper around Ruby selenium binding. It has many easy ways to do things. Or atleast include a line to answer in watir and tag watir tag as well and you will get a help.

Comment: I'm seeing this same behavior on macOS and Linux - tried numerous different strategies, environments, and the arrow keys always just scroll the page.